# ivy brings also com.springsource.org.joda.time

Tags: jodatime, ivy, spring-batch

I'm using ivy for a spring batch project.

*ivy.xml*

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="apache" module="hello-ivy"/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="commons-lang" name="commons-lang" rev="2.0"/>
        <dependency org="commons-cli" name="commons-cli" rev="1.0"/>
        <dependency org="commons-net" name="commons-net" rev="3.1" />

        <dependency org="com.jcraft" name="jsch" rev="0.1.48"/><!-- used for SFTP-->
        <dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.17"/>
        <dependency org="com.google.guava" name="guava" rev="14.0-rc2"/>
        <dependency org="joda-time" name="joda-time" rev="2.1"/>

        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-aspects" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE"/>
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-aop" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE"/>
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-context" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE"/>
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-core" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE"/>
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-test" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-beans" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-jdbc" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />

        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-tx" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-asm" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-expression" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-context-support" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />

        <dependency org="org.springframework.batch" name="spring-batch-core" rev="2.1.9.RELEASE"/>
        <dependency org="org.springframework.batch" name="spring-batch-infrastructure" rev="2.1.9.RELEASE"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

*ivysettings.xml*

```
<ivysettings>
<settings defaultResolver="spring.chain"/>
<resolvers>
    <chain name="spring.chain">
        <url name="com.springsource.repository.bundles.release">
            <ivy pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/release/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
            <artifact pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/release/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
        </url>
        <url name="com.springsource.repository.bundles.external">
            <ivy pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
            <artifact pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
        </url>
        <ibiblio name="ibiblio" m2compatible="true"/>
    </chain>
</resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Everything was great until I needed joda2. The problem here is that ivy is bringing something like com.springsource.org.joda.time-1.6.0.jar and also joda-time-2.1.jar. Is there a way I can make ivy to not bring all those clones jar from spring(com.springsource.org.joda.time-1.6.0.jar, com.springsource.org.apache.regexp-1.5.0.jar etc)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependencies can be excluded using the [exclude](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/exclude.html) directive within the ivy file.

```
<exclude module="com.springsource.org.joda.time"/>
```

A second feature of this example is the use of the [ibiblio](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/ibiblio.html) resolver to retrieve content from Maven repositories.

Finally, the example includes a call to the ivy [cleancache](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cleancache.html) task. This is required if you substantially change your resolver settings. It will ensure ivy doesn't re-use stale data in it's cache.

## Example

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="resolve" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="resolve">
        <ivy:resolve/>
        <ivy:report todir="build/ivy" graph="false"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean-all" depends="clean">
        <ivy:cleancache/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Notes:

- Features a "clean-all" target that will purge the ivy cache
- The report ivy task is useful for generating a dependency management report.

### ivysettings.xml

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="central"/>
    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
        <ibiblio name="springsource-external" m2compatible="true" root="http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external"/>
    </resolvers>
    <modules>
        <module name="com.springsource.*" resolver="springsource-external"/>
    </modules>
</ivysettings>
```

Notes:

- Defaults to Maven Central.
- Restrieves the repackaged springsource bundles from their "external" Maven repository
- This approach gives more control compared to using the "chain" resolver.

### ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="apache" module="hello-ivy"/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="commons-lang" name="commons-lang" rev="2.0"/>
        <dependency org="commons-cli" name="commons-cli" rev="1.0"/>
        <dependency org="commons-net" name="commons-net" rev="3.1" />

        <dependency org="com.jcraft" name="jsch" rev="0.1.48"/><!-- used for SFTP-->
        <dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.17"/>
        <dependency org="com.google.guava" name="guava" rev="14.0-rc2"/>
        <dependency org="joda-time" name="joda-time" rev="2.1"/>

        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-aspects" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE"/>
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-aop" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE"/>
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-context" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE"/>
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-core" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE"/>
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-test" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-beans" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-jdbc" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />

        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-tx" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-asm" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-expression" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-context-support" rev="3.1.2.RELEASE" />

        <dependency org="org.springframework.batch" name="spring-batch-core" rev="2.1.9.RELEASE"/>
        <dependency org="org.springframework.batch" name="spring-batch-infrastructure" rev="2.1.9.RELEASE"/>

        <exclude module="com.springsource.org.joda.time"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Note:

- Has an "exclude" tag to prevent the resolution of the joda time module repackaged by springsource.

Comment: this won't solve the problem. it still downloads com.springsource.org.joda.time-1.6.0.jar

Comment: @user1995187 Oops, you're right. I didn't purge my ivy cache. I've re-written my answer hope it helps